# R read csv with ="" formatting

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I have a csv where each value is wrapped in a quote with an equals sign before it, like so:

```
="#",="NAME",="SM",="SRM",="SNM",="TMG",="PIL",="TIP",="TIZ"
="1",="A.Aaronsen",="0",="0",="0",="0",="0",="0",="0"
="2",="J.Jeff",="0",="0",="0",="0",="3",="0",="0"
="4",="C.Corr",="0",="0",="0",="0",="1",="0",="0"
="5",="F.Taylor",="0",="0",="0",="0",="2",="0",="0"
="6",="J.Morris",="0",="0",="0",="0",="3",="0",="0"
```

I can't work out how to read this in so that I just have the values and the columns are of the appropriate type. The first column is the col names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file with `readLines`, remove the `=` symbol and read it with `read.csv`.

```
read.csv(text = gsub('=', '', readLines('data.csv'), fixed = TRUE))
```

Testing this as text -

```
text <- '="#",="NAME",="SM",="SRM",="SNM",="TMG",="PIL",="TIP",="TIZ"
="1",="A.Aaronsen",="0",="0",="0",="0",="0",="0",="0"
="2",="J.Jeff",="0",="0",="0",="0",="3",="0",="0"
="4",="C.Corr",="0",="0",="0",="0",="1",="0",="0"
="5",="F.Taylor",="0",="0",="0",="0",="2",="0",="0"
="6",="J.Morris",="0",="0",="0",="0",="3",="0",="0"'

read.csv(text = gsub('=', '', text, fixed = TRUE))

#  X.       NAME SM SRM SNM TMG PIL TIP TIZ
#1  1 A.Aaronsen  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#2  2     J.Jeff  0   0   0   0   3   0   0
#3  4     C.Corr  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
#4  5   F.Taylor  0   0   0   0   2   0   0
#5  6   J.Morris  0   0   0   0   3   0   0
```